# Get Color of certain point on moving 2D background

Tags: colors, background, xna, point, 2d-games

I am trying to build a simple 2D-game where a skier has to move along in a certain "corridor".

[Screenshot of the game](http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/8420/unbenanntmke.png)

Therefore I created a seamless background and move it along the screen from right to left. The background texture is three times the screen width - and I plot the texture at two positions to create the seamless illusion.

The skier can move up an down and should get points as long as he stays in the corridor (which is completely white), if he gets outside (slightly grayish color), he gets negative points - indicating a false behavior.

My question

Is there an easy and fast way to get the color of the pixel with the current position of the ski tip? Since I know the position of the ski tip on the screen, could I also use the backBuffer for this?

I tried to get the color by using:

```
    backgroundTexture.GetData<Color>(0, sourceRectangle, slopeColor, 0,1);
```

Where sourceRectangle is moved along with the skitip and slopeColor is a color array with one entry.

Comment: i could resolve the issue now, but i don't know if it's the best solution...

i created a 1D color array to save the whole background texture and check if the current position of the skitip is white or not.
but since the background moves to the left - the current position of the skitip is not the sum of skitipPosition + backgroundPosition, but the difference... :-/

stupid signedness error

Comment: Your looking for "Per Pixel Collision"

Comment: Accessing data from the backbuffer (or any buffer on the GPU) is going to be slow. Try to keep the data you are using on the CPU.

Comment: I think you're heading in the right direction. I would just create a simple texture with "good" and "bad" areas. Since you know where the ski tip is, you can compare against that instead. You'll never display this texture, so you'll never go to the GPU. You can scroll it just as you do the actual texture to keep them in sync.